# urdu strings looking same but in comparison found unequal python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, urdu

In my application, I've list of (Urdu) words in text file, (currently single word like this)

[image]

and I've another text file having string of urdu (currently single word like this and exactly same)

[image]

Now I need to find if string file's string has any word that exists in word's file. For this, I'm reading both file into lists like this;

// reading text file of strings...

```
fileToRead = codecs.open('string.txt', mode, encoding=encoding)
fileData = fileToRead.read()
lstFileData = fileData.split('\n')


wordListToRead = codecs.open('words.txt', mode, encoding=encoding)
wordData = wordListToRead.read()
lstWords = wordData.split('\n')
```

I'm simply traversing list like this;

```
for string in lstFileData:
    if string in lstWords:
        // do further work
```

and its not working And I don't know Why? Although string is 'فلسفے' and lstWords has this string in it. Do I need to add some encoding? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: it should work as it is, you better add a bit more code

Comment: okay let me add it in detail.

Comment: please check updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May be it helped out someone like me

Although it sounds like fun but Issue was in `file encoding type`. I opened up file in simple notepad to make some changes and saved it. It changed my file from `utf-8` to `utf-8 BOM`. And my code wasn't working on it. Once I created new file in notepad++ in utf-8, Same code started working fine. (Because issue was not in code, it was in file encoding)

Comment: It might well help future readers, but it's quite unlikely to be found with the current, very specific title; consider to change it to something more general like "strings looking the same compare unequal" or similar. Btw: the correct encoding to open files with UTF8 BOM is called "utf-8-sig" in Python. Otherwise (if you decode with "utf-8") the BOM character will stick to the beginning of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it out in python3 and it seems to work for me:

```
lstWords = ['a', 'فلسفے', 'b']
string = 'فلسفے'
if string in lstWords:
    print("yes")
```

Edit: Again, just tested your updated code with file IO and it works fine (I did not specify an encoding). Here is a link of it working: https://trinket.io/python3/3890d8b261

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same thing and It is assumed to work but it is not.

Comment: I think there is something else going on. Look at the link in my updated answer to see the code working just fine in python3.

Comment: Yes.. Issue was in file. I opened it in notepad and updated..and this thing changed it from utf-8 to utf-8 BOM. I guessed that was making issue. Once I made new file in notepad++ and saved it as utf-8. Same code started working fine.